# Mammal Statistics about Natural Death Versus Being Killed?

Tags: mammals, statistics, death

Is there data determining what percentage of mammals die a natural death (disease, old age) and what percentage die due to being killed and/or eaten by other mammals?

In watching wildlife documentaries over the years I'm accustomed to footage of mammals killing each other. So it makes me curious if wildlife mammals are more or less likely to be "murdered" by other mammals than humans are to be murdered by humans.

Comment: Incidentally I posted the question here, as there's no SE site for wildlife, and [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306442/seeking-a-site-about-wildlife) directed me here.

Comment: This question is wrong on meta, I move it accordingly.

Comment: I think this question is very broad because "mammals" are a very diverse group, and because predators often target the weak and sick: do you count their predation as a natural death or not? "Murder" is also not a concept that should be applied to animals in the natural world because murder is a human social construct.